What does it mean for an algebra to be block diagonal?
Trying to understand the proof of the following:
Let $\Phi: B(H) \to B(H)$ be a unital quantum channel with Kraus operators $A_i$ for $i = 1, \dotsc, n$.
Then the algebra generated by $A_1, \dotsc A_n$ is a *-algebra which depends only on $\Phi$.

What does the author mean when they say that the algebra is block diagonal?
Paper here: https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0309390

It just means that formula before the author says “block diagonal”, namely $A = \sum_j p_jAp_j$ (and ${p_j}_j$ being a PVM).

Thank you! :) :)
